# Custom Script Eval error when developing a lightning component in an organization with namespace

Tags: lightning-aura-components, namespace

I'm getting a "sorry to interrupt" error modal when trying a custom component I'm building. The component doesn't even load (the specified action in the `afterScriptsLoaded` doesn't even run).

The message shows:

> Custom Script Eval error [SecureDOMEvent: [object Event]{ key: {"namespace":"ltngtr"} }]

Where "ltngtr" is my org's namespace, of course.

The component's syntax is like this:

```
<aura:component>
    <ltng:require scripts="{!$Resource.MyCustomLibraryJS}" afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.doInit}"/>

    <aura:attribute name="code" type="String" access="global"/>

    ...

</aura:component>
```

I've tried adding the namespace to the JS file (like `{!$Resource.ltngtr__MyCustomLibraryJS}`), and it didn't change the results.

And my `.app` page is calling it like this:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <ltngtr:MyComponent code="test"/>
</aura:application>
```

"MyCustomLibraryJS" is a static resource JavaScript file of a custom JS library I'm using.

Comment: Did you check you library compatibilty here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console. Also Where does your debug stop you from console when you put breakpoints?

Comment: No, none. The component doesn't even load. Nothing on the console.

Comment: Did you have any evals() in your library? Because https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/228679/lightning-support-for-eval-in-summer-18

Comment: Nope, no `eval`s anywhere. It looks like a namespace error. When I comment the entire component code, just leaving an empty div with "Hello world", and also commenting the library import (`ltng:require`), there are no errors.

Comment: please check you have any occurrence of `eval` in `MyCustomLibraryJS` file?

Comment: My guess is it has to do with the library. I would give a try 
 https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console

Comment: Also **Even though window.counter looks like a global declaration, counter is attached to the LockerService secure window object and therefore is a namespace variable, not a global variable.** https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/12/lightning-components-code-sharing.html

Comment: Changing the library worked to avoid the error. Now to make the library to work is another, different, issue. Thank you for your help. It really was the library.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its looks like an issue with your library. When you encounter errors related to the external libraries the first place to look for is checking your library against [Locker console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console).

As a reference, here are some best practices around for creating custom js libraries with locker service compatibility. [Sharing JavaScript Code Across Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/security_share_code.htm)